# как реализовать выпуклость у блока?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

Всем привет. Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким способом лучше и легче реализовать данное дело? [image: design]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Лучше, наверное, SVG, но можно и стилями. Грязно получилось, но направление вот:

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #000000 0%, #771618 50%, #7a1315 60%, #300e12 100%);
}

.pocket {
  background-color: #ccc;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid solid none;
  border-color: #888;
  border-radius: 25px 25px 0 0;
  margin-top: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0.35;
}

.bulb {
  background-color: #ccc;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: 2px solid #888;
  position: relative;
  clip-path: polygon(-50% 0, 150% 0, 150% 50%, -50% 50%);
  display: inline-block;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.bulb:before,
.bulb:after {
  content: "";
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
  border-color: #888;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: none solid solid none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px #ccc;
  clip-path: polygon(0 10px, 100% 10px, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}

.bulb:before {
  left: -23px;
}

.bulb:after {
  right: -23px;
  transform: scalex(-1)
}

.pocketcontnent {
  margin-top: -125px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}

.button {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: #888;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.button:before,
.button:after {
  width: 4px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  left: 23px;
}

.button:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.button:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="pocket">
  <div class="bulb">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="pocketcontnent">
  <div class="button">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Всё отлично) огромное спасибо)